# Specify multiple data types for colClasses in R

Tags: r

If a data file I want to analyze in R has multiple data types and I want to call colClasses to specify the data types expected for individual columns, how would I go about doing that? The sample file I am using is: http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/_static/trees91.csv

For example, when I type

```
tree <- read.csv("trees91.csv", header=T, sep=",", dec=".", colClasses=c(C,N,REP,LFBCC,STBCC,RTBCC="integer", CHBR="character", "double"), nrows=70)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : object 'N' not found
```

There are 28 columns overall and the columns with differing data types are interspersed throughout the file. For example, the first two columns are all integer values, whereas the third column has character values, and thus forth. What I want to do is specify which columns contain integer values (columns C,N,REP,LFBCC,STBCC, and RTBCC), the one that has character values (CHBR), and specify that the rest of the columns contain decimal values.

I realize that in this instance, simply calling read.table would handle the job with no appreciable loss in speed but I am using this file to practice analyzing larger files in which using colClasses would be useful. I also realize that I could simply specify that the CHBR column is of the type "character" and leave R to set all other column types to the default type, but my goal is to empirically declare all column data types.

Comment: If you are simply defining `colClasses` for speed-up, you would be better off with using `fread` from package data.table. Also, `colClasses` doesn't expect a named vector. The column classes must be defined by position.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Roland! But if colClasses doesn't expect a named vector, why does it recognize the command colClasses=c(CHBR="character")? Wouldn't that be an example of a named vector? It executes fine when I do that.

Comment: It accepts a named vector, but the names are ignored.

Comment: @Roland ffrom `data.table`'s `colClasses` documentation: "A vector of classes to be assumed for the columns. Recycled as necessary, or if the character vector is named, unspecified values are taken to be NA."

Comment: @kayaker243 I'm not sure what you want to tell me.

Comment: @Roland your comment said the names are ignored, whereas the documentation suggests they're not.

Comment: @kayaker243 I was refering to `read.table`'s parameter. Also, at that time it was a different version of `data.table` and `fread` is still being developed.

Comment: Ah, I'd meant `read.table`.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify using either one:

> colClasses = c("integer", "integer", "character", "character")

or

> colClasses = list(integer = 1:2, character = 3:4)